# Take out Date and hour in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I do have below DateTime column inside NRAW table:

DateTime

- 09-AUG-31 01.02.00
- 09-AUG-31 01.00.00
- 09-AUG-31 02.02.00
- 09-AUG-31 02.00.00
- 09-AUG-31 03.02.00
- 09-AUG-31 03.00.00

How can I take out the date and time as below format:
(Take out any hour value, with **00 value for both min and seconds ONLY**)

- 09-AUG-31 01.00.00
- 09-AUG-31 02.00.00
- 09-AUG-31 03.00.00

Answer (score 1):

not tested but something you can do like.

```
SELECT DateTime_col
   FROM NRAW
   WHERE EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM
   TO_DATE(DateTime_col, 'YY-Mon-DD HH:MI:SS'))='00'
   AND EXTRACT(SECOND FROM
   TO_DATE(DateTime_col, 'YY-Mon-DD HH:MI:SS'))='00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested Query:

```
Select dateTimeCol from NRAW where to_char(datetimeCol,'MI:SS') = '00:00'
```